# How do I sum rows inside of pandas crosstab and make a new crosstab?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, crosstab

I have data from an excel sheet I have summarized in a pandas crosstab. I want to categorize the data further by summing related rows.

Here is my crosstab:

> ```
> class_of_orbit         Elliptical  GEO  LEO  MEO  All
> users
> Civil                           0    0   36    0   36
> Civil/Government                0    0    2    0    2
> Commercial                      3   99  412    0  514
> Government                      9   14   38    0   61
> Government/Civil                0    0   10    0   10
> Government/Commercial           0    2   81    0   83
> Government/Military             0    0    1    0    1
> Military                        9   67   66    0  142
> Military/Civil                  0    0    2    0    2
> Military/Commercial             0    0    0   32   32
> All                            21  182  648   32  883
> ```

I only want 4 groups: civil, govt,commercial, and military. If "Government" is in the name, I want to sum all the rows that contain it. If "Military" is in the name I want to sum the rows into a military row....

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### `pd.crosstab`

Do it from the start

```
pd.crosstab(df.users.str.split('/').str[0], df.class_of_orbit)
```

---

#### `groupby`

On top of what you already have.  If you pass a callable to `groupby` it will apply that to the index and use the result to group by.

```
xtab.groupby(lambda x: x.split('/')[0]).sum()

            Elliptical  GEO  LEO  MEO  All
All                 21  182  648   32  883
Civil                0    0   38    0   38
Commercial           3   99  412    0  514
Government           9   16  130    0  155
Military             9   67   68   32  176
​
```

Answer (score 1):

Grouping by the first part of each name yields

```
df.groupby(df.class_of_orbit.str.split('/').str.get(0)).sum()

            Elliptical  GEO LEO MEO All
class_of_orbit                  
All         21         182  648 32  883
Civil       0           0   38  0   38
Commercial  3           99  412 0   514
Government  9           16  130 0   155
Military    9           67  68  32  176
```

Answer (score 1):

Love Rafael and piRSquared answers, but if you want to sum all the rows that have just the *instance* of the group and not only where the group is the first part of the name, you could slightly alter piRsquared's answer.

You could define a helper function to check if a name has a second part and then create a second data frame with the sums of those rows which do have second parts to the name. Then sum this element-wise with the result shown by rafael and piRSquared. I left out the "All" observation but it could be calculated easily from the resulting data frame.

Hope this is okay, I'm new around here.

```
def second_parts_sum(x):
    if len(x.split('/')) > 1:
        return x.split('/')[1]
    else:
        return 'to_be_dropped'

first_parts = xtab.groupby(lambda x: x.split('/')[0]).sum()
second_parts = xtab.groupby(lambda x: second_parts_sum(x)).sum()
first_parts = first_parts[first_parts.index != 'All']
second_parts = second_parts[second_parts.index != 'to_be_dropped']
first_parts + second_parts



            Elliptical  GEO  LEO  MEO  All
Civil                0    0   50    0   50
Commercial           3  101  493   32  629
Government           9   16  132    0  157
Military             9   67   69   32  177
```